# Change a href=# to javascript:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I asked before on how to load a div's content (A url) by clicking a button and not on page load before and I got this code as an answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(id){
        if ($('#' + id).html() == '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=SOMETHING&from=en&to=de&text=Hello', // your url to microsoft translator
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#' + id).html(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#' + id).html('The resource could not be loaded');
                }
            });
        }

        $('#' + id).toggle(); // Toggle div visibility
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggleDiv('a')">Show/Hide Value</a>
<div id="a" style="display:none"></div>
```

First of all it doesn't work correctly and always show "The resource could not be loaded" if you put a txt link like (http://knowpersia.com/a.txt) it doesn't work either.
Secondly the Show/Hide Value link uses a href=# and onclick system to work. When I use it on my website it gets back to the homepage when I click it. Is there a way to change it to something like:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('a')">Show/Hide Value</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an `id` to the `toggleDiv()` function, and you're passing a collection of objects -> `toggleDiv('a') // Nop`.
Also, if you're using jQuery, I suggest you get rid of that ugly inline code. Then, you can pass jQuery objects into your function:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Show/Hide Value</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

.

```
var toggleDiv = function($el) {
    if ($el.empty()) { // You can just use `empty()`
        $.ajax({
            url : 'api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=SOMETHING&from=en&to=de&text=Hello', // your url to microsoft translator
            success : function (data) {
                $el.html(data);
            },
            error : function () {
                $el.html('The resource could not be loaded');
            }
        });
    }
    $el.toggle(); // Toggle div visibility
};

$('#link').click(function(){ toggleDiv($('#content')); });
```

Comment: Dear elclanrs, I'm really new in using java into my html could you please tell me how I can implement this code into the html file? I mean the whole process so that when the user clicks the Show/Hide Value link he/she will see the output by microsoft translator?!